# Eclipse SplashHandler progress monitor not being updated

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an eclipse product and I'm trying to get the progress monitor on my SplashHandler to appear and be updated as workbench loads. I have:

- plugin_customization.ini setting the org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP=true
- a custom SplashHandler extending AbstractSplashHandler
- a 'splashhandlers' extension declaring my custom SplashHandler and a binding with my product
- custom code that draws UI controls on the resulting dialog including a ProgressMonitor that gets instantiated in #getBundleProgressMonitor

What I'm seeing:

- Splash appears and runs perfectly except the monitor is never see or updated. The monitor's label neve3r gets updated but will display text if explicitly set there
- only call to #getBundleProgressMonitor is from my SplashHandler's own #init
- #updateUI method that never gets called

What should happen? I see no references in my workspace for #updateUI. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you use `Platform.createAndRunWorkbench` to run the Eclipse workbench or does your RCP do something else? It is `createAndRunWorkbench` that calls `getBundleProgressMonitor`.

Comment: Yes `PlatformUI`, sorry. Looks like we are looking at different Eclipse versions. Eclipse 4.3 Workbench calls `getBundlerProgressMonitor` in `Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench`, Eclipse 3.x uses a completely different method.

Comment: Yes I am using that code and, tracing through, I see:  MySplashHandler.init() line: 161  
Workbench$6.run() line: 773  
SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
Workbench.createSplashWrapper() line: 794  
Workbench.access$5(Workbench) line: 712  
Workbench$5.run() line: 590  
Realm.runWithDefault(Realm, Runnable) line: 332  
Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Display, WorkbenchAdvisor) line: 567  
PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Display, WorkbenchAdvisor) line: 150  But I don't see any subsequent calls to the progress monitor.